# Yii2 db mysql connection throw ssh port 33060

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have problem with connecting to mysql database throw ssh on port 33060,
My conf :

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase',
'emulatePrepare' =>true,
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I have open ssh tunel when I try to connect, and i have an error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What am I doing wrong? Is possible in Yii2 to connect throws ssh?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: may be username or password you are entering is wrong.

Comment: username and password are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was solve this problem... :

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=33060;dbname=myDatabase',
'emulatePrepare' =>true,
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
'charset' => 'utf8',
 ];
```

It must be 127.0.0.1  not localhost. 
Thanks for all answers !! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your main issues would be that you have not specified the port:

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=33060;dbname=myDatabase',
'emulatePrepare' =>true,
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I assume that you meant to put 33060 as opposed to 3306.

Comment: I was try with  this conf with port, and not working. my tunnel look : ssh -L 33060:localhost:3306 ubuntu@serverAddress.pl

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad english!

Although it is strange this error in localhost, try to make the grant in MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pass';
```

Comment: I dont  know, i don have this problem in Yii1, in Yii1 all working fine with this configuration... this problem i have only in yii2.